# android.text.BoringLayout declares multiple JSON fields named mPaint?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Can anyone tell me what in the hell is going on here?

```
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955): com.goosesys.dta_pta_test fatal error : Unable to start service com.goosesys.dta_pta_test.BGCollectorProc@4232c178 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.goosesys.dta_pta_test/.BGCollectorProc (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.text.BoringLayout declares multiple JSON fields named mPaint
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.goosesys.dta_pta_test.BGCollectorProc@4232c178 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.goosesys.dta_pta_test/.BGCollectorProc (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.text.BoringLayout declares multiple JSON fields named mPaint
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2515)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:133)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4810)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.text.BoringLayout declares multiple JSON fields named mPaint
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:122)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
02-06 09:51:41.609: E/ACRA(15955):  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
```

App was working brilliantly last night, refactored this morning and now this. I'm assuming it's something to do with object -> JSON (via Gson), but I'm unsure of how to fix it, because the error message is bloody useless!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315431/gson-tostring-gives-error-illegalargumentexception-multiple-json-fields-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out shortly after posting this. It was all due to my objects inheriting from my BaseDB class. So when it came to JSON/GSON serializing, it hit the BaseDB class and fell over.

Fix was to add the `transient` modifier to anything I didn't want serialized. Worked like a charm!